# Bash Script Modular calling of functions from an array

Tags: bash, function, shell, ubuntu, scripting

I want a script for easy installation of packages/programs/tools everytime I install my ubuntu and I want it to be modular for easy adding/removing of packages but there seems to be a problem calling functions with eval.

A simplified version of my code is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARRAY=("program 1" true fn_program1, "program 2" true fn_program2)

function fn_program1 {
    echo "IT'S WORKING!!"
}
function fn_program2 {
    echo "IT'S WORKING TOO!!"
}

for ((i=0; i<${#ARRAY[@]}; i+=3)); do
    if [ ! "${ARRAY[$i+1]}" = "false" ]; then
        eval ${ARRAY[$i+2]}
    fi
done
```

and this is my console when executing

```
Linux$ ./script.sh
./script.sh: línea 18: fn_program1,: command not found
IT'S WORKING TOO!!
```

Notice how if we add a new function

```
#!/bin/bash

ARRAY=("program 1" true fn_program1, "program 2" true fn_program2, "program 3" true fn_program3)

function fn_program1 {
    echo "IT'S WORKING!!"
}
function fn_program2 {
    echo "IT'S WORKING TOO!!"
}
function fn_program3 {
    echo "IT'S WORKING THREE!!"
}

for ((i=0; i<${#ARRAY[@]}; i+=3)); do
    if [ ! "${ARRAY[$i+1]}" = "false" ]; then
        eval ${ARRAY[$i+2]}
    fi
done
```

this is the result when executing

```
~/Linux$ ./script.sh
./script.sh: línea 21: fn_program1,: command not found
./script.sh: línea 21: fn_program2,: command not found
IT'S WORKING THREE!!
```

I can't seem to figure out why this happens and how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: You're trying to run `fn_program1,` instead of `fn_program1`, note the comma.

Comment: As Biffen indicated. You know that shell arrays aren't delimited by commas (you do that correctly for the other arguments) but you are sticking a comma after each "group" of array indices and that is causing the problem.

Comment: Also, if you are just calling the functions by name like this then you don't need `eval` here at all. (Not that I think this model is a good idea, but that's a different story entirely.)

Comment: To be really modular, you may consider putting all your code snippets as separate scripts in a directory, links to the active ones among these scripts in a second one and use `run-parts` on that, see manpage `run-parts(8)`.

Comment: I actually expected to be a silly error, but I didn't expect to be that silly. Im an idiot xD Thank you man!